# Pandas: Get the only value of a series or nan if it does not exist

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a bit more complex operation on a dataframe where I compare two rows which can be anywhere in the frame.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

D = {'A':['a','a','c','e','e','b','b'],'B':['c','f','a','b','d','a','e']\
 ,'AW':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'BW':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]}
P = pd.DataFrame(D)
P = P.sort_values(['A','B'])
P['AB'] = P.A+'_'+P.B
P['AWBW'] = P.AW+P.BW
```

Now what I am doing here is that I have pairings of strings in `A` and `B`, for example `a_c` which I call `AB`. And I have the reverse pairing `c_a` as well. I sum over the numbers `AW` and `BW` for each pairing, called `AWBW`.

Now I want to subtract the summed value of `a_c` from the value of `c_a` and do the same thing for every string pairing where both variants exist. All other values should just be `NaN`, so my result should look like this:

```
   A  AW  B  BW   AB  AWBW  RowDelta
0  a   1  c  10  a_c    11     -22.0
1  a   2  f  20  a_f    22       NaN
5  b   6  a  60  b_a    66       NaN
6  b   7  e  70  b_e    77      33.0
2  c   3  a  30  c_a    33      22.0
3  e   4  b  40  e_b    44     -33.0
4  e   5  d  50  e_d    55       NaN
```

I have almost solved the way to do this, but there's one problem left I'm stuck at.

Here's my solution so far:

```
for i,row in P.iterrows():
  P.ix[i,'RowDelta'] = row['AWBW']\
   - P[(P['A'] == row.AB[2]) & (P['B'] == row.AB[0])]['AWBW'].get(0,np.nan)
```

The problem is that `P[(P['A'] == row.AB[2]) & (P['B'] == row.AB[0])]['AWBW']` returns a series which is either empty or has exactly one element whose index however is variable.

Now the `series.get` method solves the problem of returning `NaN` when the series is empty but it wants a definitive index value, in this case I use `0`, but I can not get a dynamic index there.

I can not do this for example

```
T = P[(P['A'] == row.AB[2]) & (P['B'] == row.AB[0])]['AWBW']
T.get(T.index[0],np.nan)
```

because there is no index if the series is empty and this leads to an error when doing `T.index[0]`. Same goes for my attempts using `iloc`.

Is there a way to dynamically get the unknown one index of a series if it has one element (and never more than one) while at the same time handling the case of an empty series?

Comment: start by merging a split of `'AB'` on its reversed self.  `AB = P.AB.str.split('_', expand=True)` followed by `AB.merge(AB, left_on=[0, 1], right_on=[1, 0])`.

Comment: I made it work, thanks. I will answer my own question with this then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit goes to [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared) for pointing me into the right direction for the solution:

```
AB = P.AB.str.split('_', expand=True)
AB = AB.merge(AB, left_on=[0, 1], right_on=[1, 0],how='inner')[[0,1]]
AB = AB.merge(P,left_on=[0,1], right_on=['A','B'])[['A','AW','B','BW']]
AB = AB.merge(P,left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['B','A'])[['AW_x','BW_x','AW_y','BW_y','AB']]
AB['RowDelta'] = AB.AW_y+AB.BW_y-AB.AW_x-AB.BW_x
P = P.merge(AB[['AB','RowDelta']],on='AB',how='outer')
```

Maybe it can be made shorter or nicer, it works for sure.